# How to send XML data via HTTP POST with Android

Tags: android, web-services, http, soap, http-post

i am developing an Android client to do the following HTTPRequest and read the response. i created the back end and tested with a web service tester tool. this snippet was taken by that tool. since Android has limited support for SOAP i am looking for a way of doing this with HTTP POST. can anybody tell me a way to do this.

```
POST /demo/internalsoapgateway HTTP/1.1
Host: myIP:PORT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
InteractiveMode: false
Authorization: Basic aWZzYXBwOmlmc2FwcA==
Accept-Language: en-US
SOAPAction: urn:soap_access_provider:BrowseCountry:QueryTrnCountry
User-Agent: Java/1.5.0_11
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 381

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <TRN_COUNTRY_QUERY xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:browse_country_query_trn_country_request" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

        </TRN_COUNTRY_QUERY>

 </soap:Body>   

</soap:Envelope>
```

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Sending pictures to a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415390/sending-pictures-to-a-web-server)