# is there any API to upload images to server from android app

Tags: java, android, image

hi in my app i a have created an profile page and in that i am adding images to the page.
I want to send the images to the server database which is written in PHP.

I have two option of getting the image. one is to take a new pic and the other is selecting pic from the existing library of android device.

i am able to take new pic or select a one, now i want to send it to an URL as follows
http://siva.com/image/upload.php

is there any API for it

pls help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my answer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415390/sending-pictures-to-a-web-server/5415470#5415470).This help you to upload photos to web server through web service.