# How to generate a SOAP request from a WSDL in Android

Tags: java, android, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a WSDL file, and also i can retrieve the XSD file as well, in a server. i need to read either WSDL or XSD and generate a SOAP request accordingly in Android.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use can kSoap for SOAP request.Please check my answer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415390/sending-pictures-to-a-web-server/5415470#5415470).