# Android 2.3.3 Connection Bugs

Tags: android

Is there a bug to send file and data to the server using android 2.3.3?
because my file and data cannot be uploaded but when run the code by using Java project it works fine and all of them uploaded. I'm using the following code [Sending pictures to a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415390/sending-pictures-to-a-web-server)
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Client side or server side?

Comment: Would you mind to post the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the internet permission in the ManiFest file?

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```