# How to upload Image files from Android to .Net C# ( IIS )?

Tags: android, file-upload

I am quiet new to android development.Can some one help me to proceed on uploading the images from android apps to the .net server(IIS).

I am creating a simple application in android which uploads the images to the .net server.and all the uploaded images are shown in the asp.net site pages.

any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Android:How to upload .mp3 file and image to http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785803/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-and-image-to-http-server)

above link has the information for transferring mp3 files to http server. you could use the same for images.