# multipart/form-data enctype json for android

Tags: android, json

I want to upload image and its information. I wanna to use **multipart/ form** data json for android. I have also seen this Stack Overflow question [Android:How to upload .mp3 file and image to http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785803/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-and-image-to-http-server)

but it didn't worked for me.

This is my code:

```
        protected void doFileUpload(){
            Intent i = getIntent();
            String path = i.getStringExtra("pathimage");
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            String existingFileName = path;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
            String responseFromServer = "";
            String urlString = Constants.url_create_store;
              try
              {
               //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
              FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               URL url = new URL(urlString);
               // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoInput(true);
               // Allow Outputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true);
               // Don't use a cached copy.
               conn.setUseCaches(false);
               // Use a post method.
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
               dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               // create a buffer of maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               while (bytesRead > 0)
               {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               }
               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
               // close streams
               Log.e("Debug","File is written");
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();
              }
              catch (MalformedURLException ex)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
              }
              catch (IOException ioe)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
              }
              //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
              try {
                    inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
                    String str;

                    while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                         Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
                    }
                    inStream.close();
              }
              catch (IOException ioex){
                   Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
              }
            }

 }
```

and this is my logcat:

```
10-03 11:17:07.782: DEBUG/dalvikvm(119): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 706 objects / 34184 bytes in 839ms
10-03 11:17:13.052: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=shoop3.android.edu/.Activity3 (has extras) }
10-03 11:17:13.732: DEBUG/dalvikvm(468): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1652 objects / 91728 bytes in 187ms
10-03 11:17:15.162: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Displayed activity shoop3.android.edu/.Activity3: 1929 ms (total 1929 ms)
10-03 11:17:20.942: ERROR/Debug(468): File is written
10-03 11:17:24.802: ERROR/Debug(468): Server Response {"status":1}
10-03 11:17:25.272: ERROR/JSON Parser(468): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-03 11:17:25.282: DEBUG/Create Response(468): {"status":1}
10-03 11:17:25.312: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=shoop3.android.edu/.shoop3Activity }
10-03 11:17:26.825: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Displayed activity shoop3.android.edu/.shoop3Activity: 1349 ms (total 1349 ms)
10-03 11:19:24.372: DEBUG/SntpClient(67): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: yup , I try this tutorial , but didnt work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785803/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-and-image-to-http-server

Comment: are you getting any errors ?, if yes then upload the error logs in question. it will help a lot.

Comment: sorry I dont have reputation enough , so i cant post . it show error parsing data Org, Json Exception , do u have any tutorial please?

Comment: there is a **edit** link below the android,json tags, click on it, and paste the error log in question.

Comment: You have a JSONException, that means there is some problem while you are parsing the JSON response. Make sure all your key value name pairs are correct and in proper order. We would be able to help you more if you upload your code along with the logcat

Answer (score 3):

You can use this SimpleMultipartEntity class for sending Multipart data :

```
public class SimpleMultipartEntity implements HttpEntity {

private final static char[] MULTIPART_CHARS = "-_1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        .toCharArray();

private String boundary = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
boolean isSetLast = false;
boolean isSetFirst = false;

public SimpleMultipartEntity() {
    final StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    final Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        buf.append(MULTIPART_CHARS[rand.nextInt(MULTIPART_CHARS.length)]);
    }
    this.boundary = buf.toString();

}

public void writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds() {
    if (!isSetFirst) {
        try {
            out.write(("--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    isSetFirst = true;
}

public void writeLastBoundaryIfNeeds() {
    if (isSetLast) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        out.write(("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    isSetLast = true;
}

public void addPart(final String key, final String value) {
    writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
    try {
        out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"\r\n")
                .getBytes());
        out.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n".getBytes());
        out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
        out.write(value.getBytes());
        out.write(("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void addPart(final String key, final String fileName,
        final InputStream fin) {
    addPart(key, fileName, fin, "application/octet-stream");
}

public void addPart(final String key, final String fileName,
        final InputStream fin, String type) {
    writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
    try {
        type = "Content-Type: " + type + "\r\n";
        out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key
                + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(type.getBytes());
        out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n".getBytes());

        final byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
        int l = 0;
        while ((l = fin.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            out.write(tmp, 0, l);
        }
        out.flush();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fin.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void addPart(final String key, final File value) {
    try {
        addPart(key, value.getName(), new FileInputStream(value));
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getBoundary() {
    return boundary;
}

public void setBoundary(String boundary) {
    this.boundary = boundary;
}

@Override
public long getContentLength() {
    writeLastBoundaryIfNeeds();
    return out.toByteArray().length;
}

@Override
public Header getContentType() {
    return new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="
            + boundary);
}

@Override
public boolean isChunked() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isRepeatable() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isStreaming() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
    outstream.write(out.toByteArray());
}

@Override
public Header getContentEncoding() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void consumeContent() throws IOException,
        UnsupportedOperationException {
    if (isStreaming()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Streaming entity does not implement #consumeContent()");
    }
}

@Override
public InputStream getContent() throws IOException,
        UnsupportedOperationException {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}

}
```

Usage :

```
String serviceUri = "service url";
    InputStream fileInputStream = mInputStream; //Your file stream
    String fileName = "your file name";
    String fileKey = "Key name what server is looking for"
    HashMap<String, String> headerparts = mHeaderParts; //Other header parts that you need to send along.

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serviceUri);
    SimpleMultipartEntity entity = new SimpleMultipartEntity();
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="
            + entity.getBoundary());
    entity.writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();

    if (headerparts != null) {
        Object[] keySet = headerparts.keySet().toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < keySet.length; i++) {
            String key = keySet[i].toString();
            String value = headerparts.get(key);
            entity.addPart(key, value);
        }
    }

    entity.addPart(fileKey, fileName, fileInputStream);
    entity.writeLastBoundaryIfNeeds();
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    try {
        mResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```