# Setting MimeType HttpURLConnection Upload

Tags: php, android

In an Android app I am uploading images using the HttpUrlConnection style shown in [Android:How to upload .mp3 file and image to http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785803/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-and-image-to-http-server) in a multipart form upload.

Everything works fine and dandy except on the receiving end I do not see the mimetype encoded to "image/jpeg" - I am receiving via PHP on an Apache server and "type" is blank no matter what I try. I have searched, prototyped and scratched, and nothing I can do seems to set this up without breaking my upload somehow or simply not working. I know its something I am misunderstanding about the POST request format but am missing it. Can someone inform me as to how to insert the mimetype for the style upload in the above link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something is wrong with your gataway,I've ever come across with a similiar problem,after a long time search,I found that my gateway changed my mimeType.May it helps.

Comment: Hmmm - the site is hosted at GoDaddy. I noticed in simple php multiform file uploads from my site in browser the mime type is set just fine using the same gateway, just not when I manually create the POST request in the App and shove the request up. Maybe my understanding is wrong - is the type in a file upload set by the sender of the POST request or the server on the receiving side? I always thought it was set by the sender.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was wrong. I just needed to manually set the MIME type myself when constructing the POST request.