# upload an image and audio in One request in android

Tags: android

How to upload an image and audio together in android?
I was successful in uploading an image and audio in one request but how to add multiple files.

I referred this link [Android:How to upload .mp3 file to http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966910/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-to-http-server) and it's perfectly working, but  I want to add another file in this request.Please help me to do this.
For that what change should I do in the android and php side.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the **httpmime-4.0.jar** and **apache-mime4j-0.4.jar** and set the entity as `MultipartEntity`.
you can use as many file as you want.

Here is the stuff,

```
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("url for upload file");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("myIdentifier", new StringBody("somevalue"));
entity.addPart("myImageFile", new FileBody(imageFile));
entity.addPart("myAudioFile", new FileBody(audioFile));

httpost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response;
response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

and for `php` side you can use these entity identifier names `"myImageFile"` and `"myAudioFile"` and move these files in appropriate folder.

Comment: if you find this answer is useful for you. then vote it, for other user.

Comment: Where to use this "httpmime-4.0.jar and apache-mime4j-0.4.jar". You didn't mention about this in your answer.

Comment: from where should I download these jars

Comment: you can download apache-mime4j-0.5.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/MNOPQR/Downloadapachemime4j05jar.htm) and httpmime-4.0.jar [here](http://www.findjar.com/jar/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0/httpmime-4.0.jar.html?all=true) and use in your project buildpath.

Comment: voted up, nice guide, would some1 also let me know how I can use this using Async task, I want user to click upload button, then multiple files with data is to upload using same method above, but after the click the activity should be finish and I have to check if network available then upload data else I do have to wait for network in background, means implement broadcast reciever, would any1 getting the follow kindly update me the best procedure to follow, I am junior

Comment: +1. It would be even better if the code showed where the httpclient came from.

Comment: Nice Answer , You deserve +1