# Send parameters along with file in android to server

Tags: android

I am using this code to send a file to server
[upload an image and audio in One request in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037717/upload-an-image-and-audio-in-one-request-in-android)

Now my problem is I want to send some string parameters along with request.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any hands on experience with this, but from looking at your code, I would think you could do it in the code below

```
entity.addPart("NEW_PARAMETER", new StringBody("some_value"));
```

Couldn't you just add more of these, and get them in your server side code just like your accessing the other values your sending?

Comment: Thanks Woody:- I will check that and reply.