# send audio file and string data to server from android

Tags: android

I want to send audio file and some string data to server from android and I am using the same as given in this link ([upload an image and audio in One request in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037717/upload-an-image-and-audio-in-one-request-in-android)), but I am getting the error where I am adding the data.

```
entity.addPart("title",new StringBody("hello"));
```

I have already add `httpmime-4.0.jar` and `apache-mime4j-0.4.jar` files through build path.

How can I do the code error free and send audiofile and data to server?

Thanks.

Comment: is it a compilation error or Runtime error?

Comment: it is showing error in code with red mark.

Comment: What is the error? Compile the project and see what you see in Problems tab?

Comment: when i put cursor on error area .it shows the message:              The type org.apache.james.mime4j.message.SingleBody cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: Did you import org.apache.james.mime4.. If yesy just clean your project and build again it should fix the problem... hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

use this .jar file "httpmime-4.0-beta2.jar" .It worked in my case