# android use Multipartentity to upload a .txt file to server

Tags: android

I try to upload a text file using MulitPartEntity but unable to upload .. my code is mention below please help me..

```
 File file = new File("/sdcard/" + strEmailAddress + ".txt");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strUrl);


        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            if (file.exists()) {
                Helper.printLogD(" file is exist ");
            }
            FormBodyPart bodyPart = new FormBodyPart("userfile",
                    (ContentBody) file);


        reqEntity.addPart(bodyPart);


        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037717/upload-an-image-and-audio-in-one-request-in-android/7038888#7038888

Comment: try this:   reqEntity.addPart("userfile",
                    new FileBody (file)); rather than creating a FormBodyPart.