# Upload file and string at the same time

Tags: java, android, http

I have successfully been able to upload files from Android to my server. I followed this [tutorial](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) and it works with no problem. Now I need to also send a string along with the file that will be added to the file name once it is uploaded. For example:

Upload my file - myFile.mp3

Upload my string = "|myString"

The file needs to be stored on my server as "myFile.mp3|myString".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just not quite sure where to place the string to upload it and how to retrieve it in the PHP code.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037717/upload-an-image-and-audio-in-one-request-in-android/7038888#7038888 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around some more and trying different things, it finally works. I added this to my java code:

```
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mystring\"" + lineEnd + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("myString" + lineEnd);
```

and this to my PHP code to get the string:

```
$myString="";       

if(isset($_POST['mystring'])) {
    $attachToFile = $_POST['myString']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible; you can only have one content-type in the header, file, or basic text (or a bunch of other things, but there are the two you're talking about). You can, however, make two seperate posts, or make one post containing bytes of the file and a string (paramater post, application www-x-form-urlencoded)

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading using **multipart/form-data** POST request, you can include other data in headers.

Check this post : [Android send a image and save url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632737/android-send-a-image-and-save-url/7632849#7632849)

Answer (score 0):

If it is absolutely unavoidable, you can put string in Request header