# Upload file to server from android 11

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I used this example (http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) to upload file from android device to server, it works fine on android 8. But it does not work with android 11. Can any one help me? :(

Comment: Also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966910/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-to-http-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. I use this example:

[**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

in a thread. it works fine. It a new experience for me and I share this for you too. :)