# Can't transfer files from emulator > 2 MB

Tags: android, http, android-emulator

I am trying to transfer files from my android emulator to my server. I observed that files of size around 2MB or greater are just not getting transferred.

Is it because of the internal memory I've provided to the emulator. If it is, should I change the way I'm transferring the file? My transfer method is similar to the only here:  [Android:How to upload .mp3 file to http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966910/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-to-http-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found the answer. I had to make a change in the PHP ini file and increase the limit to my desired size :)

So there is nothing wrong with the emulator as such, it was a problem at my webserver end.