# upload any file from any folder from sd card to server using Android

Tags: java, php, android

I am new for Android. I am trying to upload any type of file(like audio,video,document,image.. formats) from android SD card to php server, but am not getting clear code.I got some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966910/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-to-http-server) ,but they mentioned existing particular type of file & Specific path.I want all type of fie upload from SD card.

Comment: The code in the link doesn't filter on the extension neither the mime type, that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Loic. I dont know how to upload mine type and pick file from SD card.I dont want mention existing file name.If have idea share me.

Answer (score 1):

from this method u can access all file from sd card 
this is my code

```
 public void getAllFile(File dir) {
              File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

                if (listFile != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                        if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                            getAllFile(listFile[i]);
                        } else {
                             listFile[i].getName();

                                System.out.println("your file is "+listFile[i].getName());
                            }
                        }

                }
         }
```

best of luck dude :)

Answer (score 0):

//call this method to select file from device memory

```
   static Uri url;
   String path;

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("*/*");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i = Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose a file"); 

    startActivityForResult(i, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
}
```

//here you will get the path of selected file

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            if(resultCode==-1)
            {
                Log.w("Request Code", ""+requestCode);
                Log.w("Result Code", ""+resultCode);
                path = getRealPathFromURI( data.getData());
                try {
                    Log.w("Intent", data.getData().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.w("Error", e.toString());
                }
                }
        }
```

//get exact path of file -- exact path is stored in **path** variable

```
public String getRealPathFromURI (Uri contentUri)
 {
     String path = null;
     String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };

        if("content".equalsIgnoreCase(contentUri.getScheme ()))
            {
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                    path = cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
                cursor.close();
                return path;
            }
            else if("file".equalsIgnoreCase(contentUri.getScheme()))
            {
                return contentUri.getPath();
            }
            return null;
        }
```